# Why does my image tile when the background color is set css

Tags: css, background-image

When I use this code the image tiles itself:

```
.module-36{
  background:black;
  background-image: url("image.jpg"); 
}
```

But when I use this code the image is just one solid image covering the background:

```
.module-36{ 
  background-image: url("image.jpg"); 
}
```

More just curious as to why this happens so that if needed I can manipulate accordingly?

Comment: You want [`background-repeat` too](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp).  Default is repeating.  Usage: `background-repeat: repeat|repeat-x|repeat-y|no-repeat|initial|inherit`

Comment: So does that mean that when using background it automatically enables background-repeat?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Below is a link which shows you some of the different values background-repeat also accepts...

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Comment: So does that mean that when using background it automatically enables background-repeat?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `background-color:black`. That won't have the `repeat` issue you are having as it is specific to what you are trying to do.

The `background` property is a combination of several attributes including `background-repeat`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

background-repeat repeat is the default setting, so yes setting the background property overrides any previous setting of repeat.

I am unable to reproduce your problem using the CSS you have given (both examples give tiling) so something else is setting a no-repeat which then gets overridden by the background setting.

This wouldn’t happen if you used the more specific background-color property.